# Remove symbolic link /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk that had been created while installing oracle 11g

Tags: ubuntu, awk, oracle11g, installation

I am installing Oracle 11g in Ubuntu 14.04 and progressed quite well. However, I want to delete the symbolic link that had been created earlier from this command `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk`. I am following the steps from this link:[Oracle 11g installation steps in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Could you let me know how can I permanently remove that link and the files/directory created via that command?

Thanks!

Comment: check `unlink` command

Comment: Thanks! Could you let me know more about it? I am not a technical person so I am unable to find any good solution.

Comment: added some code with a sample example, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls -lrt /usr/bin/awk
-rw-r--r-- 1 ps ps 0 May 31 06:47 /usr/bin/awk #main location 

cd /usr/local/bin                              #Alternate location

ln -s /usr/bin/awk awk                          #Softlink creation

ls -lrt                                        #Varifying softlink presence 
awk -> /usr/bin/awk                             #Present

cd /usr/local/bin                              #move to alternate location

unlink awk                                     #unlink the softlink created.
```

reference :

```
whatis unlink
unlink               (1)  - call the unlink function to remove the specified file
unlink               (1p)  - call the unlink function
unlink               (2)  - delete a name and possibly the file it refers to
unlink               (3p)  - remove a directory entry
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing it. I really appreciate. I will try and let you know.